# Easiest way to split file system path into segments/sections

Tags: go, path

I want to create a list of segments from a file system path in golang.

- On Windows: `"a\b\c"` should get parsed to ["a", "b", "c"]
- On POSIX systems: `"a/b/c"` should get parsed to ["a", "b", "c"]

Looking at the [`path/filepath` package](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Split) I can only see the `Split` function, which only splits the path into two strings, the last segment and everything else.

**Is there any standard library function that would split the path into all segments out of the box?**

I can think of this workaround:

```golang
strings.Split(filepath.ToSlash(path), "/")
```

I was also thinking about using `filepath.Split`, recursively, but it ends up in an infinite loop, because the dir string contains the ending separator. See this example to understand why can't you run `Split` multiple times https://go.dev/play/p/xZ-2DML0xWK.

```golang
func mySplit(path string) []string {
    dir, last := filepath.Split(path)
    if dir == "" {
        return []string{last}
    }
    return append(mySplit(dir), last)
}
```

Comment: Iterate filepath.Split.

Comment: Thanks @Volker, if you mean run `filepath.Split` again on the directory, that won't work. Because multiple calls to Split keep returning the same directory. I added a link to Go Playground example in the issue description. I copy it here as well: https://go.dev/play/p/xZ-2DML0xWK

Answer (score 0):

```
r := strings.Split("a/b/c", "/")


r := strings.Split("a\b\c", "\")
```

Comment: This wouldn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Clean before split.

```
func mySplit(path string) []string {
    dir, last := filepath.Split(path)
    if dir == "" {
        return []string{last}
    }
    return append(mySplit(filepath.Clean(dir)), last)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filepath.Split with filepath.Clean to do the job but you need to know when to stop the loop. The following code will split the provided path and also add the root directory (eg. `/` or `C:\`) - if any - to the beginning of the slice. When the path starts with `..` it will also add that to the front of the slice. Trailing slashes will be removed.

```
func splitPath(path string) []string {
    subPath := path
    var result []string
    for {
        subPath = filepath.Clean(subPath) // Amongst others, removes trailing slashes (except for the root directory).

        dir, last := filepath.Split(subPath)
        if last == "" {
            if dir != "" { // Root directory.
                result = append(result, dir)
            }
            break
        }
        result = append(result, last)

        if dir == "" { // Nothing to split anymore.
            break
        }
        subPath = dir
    }

    slices.Reverse(result)
    return result
}
```